# Git doesnt ignore some of the files

Tags: git, github, gitignore, ignore

I know that problem seems to be asked many times, but I have no clue that do.

**.gitignore** contains `.csv`, but then I tried to commit, faced really strange behavior for me:

```
Changes to be committed:

#   new file:   regression/qw/batch_learning.ipynb
#   new file:   regression/qw/submission.csv
#   new file:   regression/qw/test.csv
#
# Untracked files:
#   cm0xg0y1.s2t.txt
#   regression/qw/train.csv
#   text analyses/submission.csv
#
```

As you can see some files ignored, some not. I know problem might be related, that git "saw" that files, but if so, `train.csv` wont be ignored. So can I ignore that files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.gitignore` file should contain `*.csv`

[edit] This is explained in man page, of course - but you need to know what [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) means first ;)

`man gitignore` says:

> (...)
>   Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) (...)